# Create a dictionary with list index as keys and input data as values

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I can't figure out how to create a dictionary that will be based on an input of a list of whole numbers (*no problem with getting the input*) and have the list indexes as keys and input data as values.

For example if the input is `[75, 48, 23, 89]` then the end result should be `[(0, 75), (1, 48), (2, 23), (3, 89)]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) and convert the result to a list as follows:

```py
l = # your list
new_list = list(enumerate(l))
```

Comment: Rule of thumb: Any question that can be answered with "use builtin function X" is a duplicate.

Comment: @Carmoreno I didn't downvote yours, btw, I guess someone disliked that you reimplemented `enumerate`...

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure if I understood your question right but this would generate a dict with the index of the list as keys and their values as values.

```
lst = [75, 48, 23, 89]

d = dict(zip(list(range(len(last))), lst))
```